# Laravel localization and named routes in case of nested Route::group's

Tags: php, laravel, localization, routes, overriding

I need to pass language code via url for localization purposes, but encountered problem with nested `Route::group`.

My routes look like this at the moment:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'employee', 'namespace' => 'Employee'], function()
{
    Route::resource('user', 'UserController', ['only' => ['show', 'index']]);
});
```

This means that I have named routes like `employee.user.show`, `employee.user.index` etc. and URL like this `/employee/user/2`, `/employee/user` etc.

I need to leave route names as is, but change my URL to such `/en/employee/user/2`, `/en/employee/user` etc., so that language code is always passed via URL.

When I try to wrap my routes with new `Route::group` like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'en'], function() {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'employee', 'namespace' => 'Employee'], function()
    {
        Route::resource('user', 'UserController', ['only' => ['show', 'index']]);
    });
});
```

I get URLs in the form I need, but route names become `en.employee.user.show`, `en.employee.user.index` etc., what is very inconvenient, cause makes me pass language all the time. My problem is similar to the one described here https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1616

**I can think now of a few solutions:**

1) do not use resources at all and define all `POST`, `GET` etc. routes manually and use `as` for route naming;

2) use `action('Employee\UserController@show')` instead of `route('employee.user.show')` and pass language as extra parameter all the time;

3) somehow override `route` method, so that every time to parameters is added one more paratemer named `lang` with language code as its value (uses locale like `route('employee.user.show', ['lang' => 'en'])`, or uses current site locale if no `lang` param provided manually), so every time I call this method I get URL like `/employee/user/2?lang=en` etc. (or receive this URL even not passing any `lang` param if current locale is set to `en`).

**On each solution:**

1) first solution is ugly, because I have to write 7 lines with extra params instead of simple short one-line resource declaration;

2) second solution makes me write all the time all namespases, controller names and method names and also add language parameter - all this is too ugly also;

**3) I need to somehow overrite `UrlGenerator`'s `route` method, so that I still can use `route` method, but with enchanced functionality. How can I override this method in Laravel 4.2?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add Google-like `lang` parameter that is automatically attached to all URLs, it is needed to override `route` helper. Here are steps:

1) create some separate file, let say `helpers_override.php` and put is somewhere, e.g. into `app` folder;

2) in `index.php` file **before** registration of Auto Loader (that is before the line `require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';`) you have to require your `helpers_override.php` (in my case like  this `require __DIR__.'/../app/helpers_override.php';`

The very `route` helper that will add `lang` parameter to every route looks like this:

```
if ( ! function_exists('route'))
{
    /**
     * Generate a URL to a named route.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @param  array   $parameters
     * @param  bool  $absolute
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Route $route
     * @return string
     */
    function route($name, $parameters = array(), $absolute = true, $route = null)
    {
        $parameters = (array) $parameters;

        if ( ! key_exists('lang', $parameters))
        {
            $parameters['lang'] = App::getLocale();
        }

        return app('url')->route($name, $parameters, $absolute, $route);
    }
}
```

As a result we do not have to create separate `Route::group` and use ugly route names like `en.employer.user.show` etc., we still preserve clear and nice `route` helper, we do not have to pass `lang` params manually all the time. We can even make some more modifications and add `lang` parameter only in case if language is different from default one.